# CSS, Internet Explorer 7: layout messed up when I click on a menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

In Internet Explorer 7, when I click on the menu in 'Categories' block, my website content slides to left.

Could you help me to debug this ?

http://69.90.160.65/~o110334/

thanks

Comment: Which version of IE are you using? I'm not seeing the problem in IE8.

Comment: I tried it in IE8 and IE8 compatibility mode and nothing seemed to shift left.  Now in both firefox and IE the background shifts down when you click on something in the Categories block.  Also, the backgrounds are different between IE and FF.

Comment: IE7 sorry, I forgot to mention. Yeah the background is fine. The main block with the content shifts to left (over the menu) in IE7

Comment: Did you fix this? I had seen the effect you referred to in IE7, but I am not seeing it now. Cool background by the way :-)

Comment: not really. The issue is still there, if you click on the menu you'll see the shift. ..and about the background: it is not my choice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to have something to do with a width and maybe positioning. If I put a `position: relative` on your id="main-inner" and **EITHER** on the id="content" I change the left margin from 240px to 239px **OR** change the id="sidebar-left" width from 240px to 239px it *seems* to work. While this may not be the final solution you seek, it does seem to indicate that it is some interaction in the width of elements and the margins that is causing your issue.